# How to create dynamic Bean?

Tags: java, reflection, taglib

I have a text file which contain comma separated data which is the attribute of our bean.

e.g. `name,age,gender,city,zipcode`

We read the text file and we have a list which contain all the attribute. Here we need to create a dynamic Bean which contain the attribute based on that list which we get after reading text file, but we have different text files with different fields. So how should I create a dynamic bean which can contain the attributes according to the list which we will get after reading test file? Please give me some solution on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a dynamic Bean,
but I would use a HashMap:

```
    HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
    values.put("name", "Sebastian Blablabla");
    values.put("city", "MyTown");
    System.out.println(values.get("name"));
    System.out.println(values.containsKey("city"));
    System.out.println(values.containsKey("zipcode"));
```

Dynamic beans by Oracle use Maps too, look here: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s0210dynamicbeans01.html

Answer (score 0):

I would just Use a Super- Class; Just like, i dont know..

```
public class Item
```